# TypeScript Angular Intellisense in html template

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I've been looking for days and I can't find an IDE or extension that gives me Intellisense in Angular html template.

I'm looking for Intelisense that lists the members of the component and makes sure I don't do casing/spelling mistakes.

Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not standard ones , but  **[`vscode-ng-language-service`](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service)** should help you.

This plugin will provide completions in template files and template strings and diagnostics for templates and Angular annotations.

you can download and install from **[`here`](https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service/releases)**

[image]

Comment: Note that this plugin is not being actively maintained which is a serious pity.